# Can NiMH type AA battery charger be used for other types like AAA, C, or D (all NiMH)?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, charging, damage, nimh

As the title states, I would like to know if a battery charger for AA NiMH batteries could be used to charge also AAA, C and D battery types (all of which also of NiMH type).

I am aware of that physically they won't fit in, therefore I would need to connect them with wires. I am asking more voltage and charging algorithms wise. Would it damage the batteries or would the charger get damaged itself? Why?

I think all of them are of same voltage.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider their current handling capability as well. This increases in order AAA AA C D.

It is safe to charge a higher capability cell from a lower capability charger.

So you will be able to safely charge AA C and D.

AAA may be able to be charged by the same charger but you need to check the specification of the battery and the charger, checking that the battery can tolerate the charge current provided by the charger.

There is a good article on NiMH charging here http://www.powerstream.com/NiMH.htm

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In this scenario, I consider using wires to connecting the batteries to the charger as not risky even without presence of any thermistor. Am I right?

Comment: I cant answer that without knowing the type of charger. Some do use temp increase to indicate end of charge. Slow chargers where the current is less than 1/10 of capacity should be safe.

Comment: I thought that based on the small relative capability when moving from AA to C or D. Thank you. I will try it and when something comes up, I will make an update.

Comment: I can confirm it works. I tried it and the outcome was satisfying. Thank you.